# display huawei install prompt

Tags: angular, huawei-developers

**CONTEXT:**

I'm working on an Angular app. I have to display a banner or popup to tell the user to prefer the mobile app instead if he's using my app on a mobile device. The ads redirect to the mobile app's page on GooglePlay or the AppStore.

Doing it for Safari was a pretty straight forward process, I just had to follow the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners

As for Chrome and other browsers, there's an install prompt available: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/

**PROBLEM:**

I also have to do it for Huawei since they developed their own AppGallery. If the user is using the Angular app on a Huawei device, then I should redirect him to the AppGallery instead of GooglePlay. I've looked for a solution but couldn't find anything so far.

- does Huawei provide a built in solution?
- should I use the normal install prompt and do something in the web manifest?